# Define a c type in bits

Tags: c, typedef

I was wondering if you could define a type in bits.
Specifically, I want to define a 24 bits type, in order to store the cumulative number of package lost in RTP.

If not, how can I memcpy 3 bytes from an int.
If I do this, I'm not sure how it'll end:

```
memcpy(pkg + 29, (&clamped_pkgs_lost)+(sizeof(char)), 3*sizeof (char));
```

Comment: @MartinJames Not relevant to `memcpy`, since you can't take the address of a bit field. But the OP shouldn't use `memcpy`.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a type with at least 24 bits using a bitfield, but a bitfield must be a member of a `struct`:

```
struct {
    unsigned pkgs_lost: 24;
};
```

Whether you use such a bitfield, or just a simple type with at least 24 bits like `unsigned long` to store the value within your application, when you copy it to the RTP packet the simplest portable way to do it is to copy it a byte at a time.  This is because the value in the RTP packet is always big-endian, and the endianness of your host is unknown.

Assuming that `pkg` is of type `unsigned char *`, you would do something like:

```
pkg[33] = pkgs_lost >> 16;
pkg[34] = pkgs_lost >> 8;
pkg[35] = pkgs_lost;
```

to place the 24-bit big endian number at byte position 33 in the outgoing packet.

Answer (score 1):

In C you can define integer types only in terms of the fundamental types or bitfields thereof.

Bitfields are quirky. You can't take their address. And they won't save you any space if you need just 24 bits, but your platform only has fundamental types of 8, 16 and 32 bits. You'd still need to use either 3 8-bit integers or 1 32-bit integer (or 1 16-bit and 1 8-bit) to store those 24 bits of yours.

For something as simple as a counter, I'd just use a 32-bit integer. If I'm interested in limiting it to 24 bit values, I have two options:

- zeroing out the 8 most significant bits and thus simulating a wrap around
- limiting the value to 2<sup>24</sup>-1, so it never grows beyond it nor wraps around

Comment: If I limit the value, I should just make a left logical shift in order to take the 3 first bytes, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can store a narrow integer in a larger integer. Just mask-off the bits you want.

```
int main() {
    long data;
    data & 0xFFFFFF;
}
```

Or, you can define a bitfield on a structure member. But don't try to write the struct to disk and open it on a different system because bitfield layouts are *not standardized*.

```
struct {
    long data:24;
};
```